# How to prohibit ordinary users to read the file '/proc/cpuinfo' in a docker?

Tags: docker, linux-kernel

Default, the file '/proc/cpuinfo' can be read by all users in a docker. So any user can get the host's info from it. I'd like to know how to prohibit ordinary users to read the file '/proc/cpuinfo' in a docker or don't get anything useful from it is also ok.  What if i chmod the file to 440?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to achieve? Why would you try to hide cpu info? Interested parties can get the same information by issuing an unprivileged "cpuid" instruction, assuming x86, but that's what you are most likely running.

Comment: I want to provide pass service.  People can deploy their applications on my machine.  I will provide a docker for every app and every docker is assigned to a sys user. For security reasons， I don't want others can see my machine's info. But that can be get by /proc/cpuinfo or /rpoc/meminfo.

Comment: Securing such a deployment is a complicated matter and obfuscating stuff like cpuinfo (which you can't do anyway, as noted earlier) or meminfo is not a significant factor. What you are looking at are possible kernel vulns, especially in syscalls which are provided, but don't have to be for the software to function. I can only recommend not playing with proc.